# Force UIWindow to use status bar from original window

Tags: ios, uikit, uiwindow

I've seen a few questions about status bars and UIWindow, but none of them gave me a solution for this exact problem.

I'd like to make a UIWindow for showing in-app notifications/toasts that appear on top of everything. A UIWindow seems the right way to do this. However, the window affects the status bar. I'd like the status bar to be driven by the original window that contains the rest of the app. Any easy way to do this?

Comment: Is your app storyboard based? or are you programatically setting root view controller?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be creating a seperate `UIWindow` to achieve this. Instead make a Custom View subclassing `UIView`, do your work in it via code or a `Nib`. And add it as a subview to your Main Window. `[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] addSubview:CustomView];`

You can also use `bringSubviewToFront` to make sure it adds above all other subviews. But it isn't necessary, would be on front in almost all typical scenarios.

Comment: Hmm, I'll have to look into this more. Wouldn't a presented view controller cover it up if I just add it to the window?